# how to create if condition for one time loading my asset library in asset UserAssetLibrary

Tags: python, blend-files

```
import bpy
def execute(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    mytool = scene.my_tool
    ual = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries['Stylized_Material_Library'].name
    if ual :
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Stylized_Material_Library allready loaded")
        return
    else:
        bpy.ops.preferences.asset_library_add(directory= mytool.my_dir)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Stylized_Material_Library Is ready To Use, Open Asset Browser")
    
    
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Hi, shabnam mansun, and welcome.  .. I see you've got an answer to this... hope it's good .. but please edit to formulate this post as an explicit question in the body: 'How do I ..  xxx', in plain words. This is partly to make the archive more searchable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Verifying Asset Library

### By Library name

```
import bpy
import pathlib

my_dir = pathlib.Path('C:\\Blender Projects\\Assets\\')


def verify_lib_name(my_dir):  # verify by key name
    ual = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries.get(my_dir.stem)
    if ual:
        print(f"{ual.name} already loaded")
    else:
        print(f"loading {my_dir} as {my_dir.stem}")
        bpy.ops.preferences.asset_library_add(directory=str(my_dir))

verify_lib_name(my_dir)
```

### By Library Path

```
import bpy
import pathlib

my_dir = pathlib.Path('C:\\Blender Projects\\Assets\\')


def verify_lib_path(my_dir):  # verify by path
    libs = bpy.context.preferences.filepaths.asset_libraries
    loaded_libs = [lib for lib in libs if lib.path == str(my_dir)]
    if loaded_libs:
        for lib in loaded_libs:
            print(f'{str(my_dir)} used by {lib.name}')
    else:
        print(f"loading {my_dir} as {my_dir.stem}")
        bpy.ops.preferences.asset_library_add(directory=str(my_dir))

verify_lib_path(my_dir)
```

### Notes

- A single library path can be associated with multiple library names.
- No Verification made for existence of path 'C:\Blender Projects\Assets\'

[image: ![Example](Untitled.png)]

Comment: how to connect penal props in this code my path prop